# How can I insert the super_admin seeder in laravel?

Tags: laravel, seed

`SuperAdminSeeder.php`

```php
    public function run()
    {
        #Super Admin Seeder
        $role = Role::where('name', 'super_admin')->first();
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'Jhon Cena',
            'email' => 'jhon@gmail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('jhoncena'),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);

        $user->role()->attach($role->id);
    }
```

> This is my SuperAdmin seeder which task is to make a user with role `super_admin`

`DatabaseSeeder.php`

```php
    public function run()
    {

        $this->call(RegionSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CountrySeeder::class);
        $this->call(LocationSeeder::class);

        $this->call(ProductSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SliderSeeder::class);
        $this->call(BannerSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SuperAdminSeeder::class);   //this is the Super Admin seeder
        $this->call(RoleSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ShopSeeder::class);
    }
```

> This is the database seeder

The error I am getting [php artisan migrate:fresh --seed]

> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Trying to get property 'id' of non-object", "E:\github\LARAVEL\Deal-Ocean\database\seeds\SuperAdminSeeder.php", [Object(App\User)])

**I am new in laravel**

Comment: Can you show me `user_role` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused no super_admin  role when you run superadmin seeder. You should add SuperAdminSeeder after RoleSeeder.

```
public function run()
{

    $this->call(RegionSeeder::class);
    $this->call(CountrySeeder::class);
    $this->call(LocationSeeder::class);

    $this->call(ProductSeeder::class);
    $this->call(SliderSeeder::class);
    $this->call(BannerSeeder::class);
    $this->call(RoleSeeder::class); //this seeder must have superadmin role
    $this->call(SuperAdminSeeder::class);   //this is the Super Admin seeder
    $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
    $this->call(ShopSeeder::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function run()
{

    $this->call(RegionSeeder::class);
    $this->call(CountrySeeder::class);
    $this->call(LocationSeeder::class);

    $this->call(ProductSeeder::class);
    $this->call(SliderSeeder::class);
    $this->call(BannerSeeder::class);

    $this->call(RoleSeeder::class);
    $this->call(SuperAdminSeeder::class);   //this is the Super Admin seeder

    $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
    $this->call(ShopSeeder::class);
}
```

> Just put the `RoleSeeder` above the `SuperAdminSeeder`.

> Because `roles` table might have a column value named `super_admin`. SO you must call the `RoleSeeder` Because there is a foreign key constriant.. And then you can insert the super admin using `SuperAdminSeeder`